# SQL Server 2014 Express dbid count is always 2 for specific DB

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
    loginame as LoginName
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame
```

Currently 10 users are logged in our `MVC` application but `NumberOfConnections` for DB is always `2` ...

Is there a limitation in SQL Server 2014 Express or why is it always 2?

Answer (score 1):

It is more you not knowing a core concept: Connnection pooling.

> Currently 10 users are logged in our MVC application

Which means NOTHING. Because that is just a session cooking.

MVC applications only use a db connection when it is USED - when a page is generated.

With 10 people that is EXTREMELY RARE. People tend not to load 100 pages a minute (and that would be low). And unless there is a lot of data, a rare case or an incompetent programmer the db connection rarely takes more then 10ms or so for a page... with 10 people occasionally doing something.... that is NOTHING.

So you have 2 connections max because nothing is going on.

And they keep on because of connection pooling - faster to keep them alive (for some time) than going through all the connecting overhead over and over again.

Comment: Thank you for helpfull explanation. But there is also a problem that wheh more then 3 customers are logged in the system, the system is very slow and all rest calls takes a lot of time. If only one customer is logged in everyhing works smoothly. Is this db problem or mvc?

Comment: This is neither nor - it is a programmer problem, most likely. As in: you need to do your job starting to debug the problem properly.